# How to fix name shadowing trap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests

when I run the code:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests   

main_api = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'    
address = 'Moscow'
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address':address})    
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
print(json_data)
```

I get the following message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

As I already researched hundreds of times, this is because of name shadowing trap: somewhere on my pc, I have folder or file with the same name. After that, I made a search on "my computer" and found several folders named "requests". They are located at:

```
C:\Users\teman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor
```

renaming does not work for this folder - I get the same error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I am fully depressed with this and can not fix it for 3 days, pls help me with this, thanks!

Comment: try to create clear `virtualenv`

Comment: Do you have `requests` package installed with pip? Try `pip install requests`. The previous commenter is rigth about the `virtualenv` though.

Comment: Directories which are not on your `PYTHONPATH` are harmless for this scenario.

Comment: thanks, creating new env helped!